# Override default JsonSerializer on serialize exception

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Is it possible, to override default Net.Core JsonSerializer or catch Exception on serialize?
Actually, when i pass wrong field type to model, required in controler(for example property is type of string i will pass int) then response look like this

```
{
   "status": 400,
   "message": "Validation error",
   "data": [   {
      "filedName": "$.Username",
      "validateErrors": ["The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.Username | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 16."]
   }]
}
```

when i print this message to user, he won't know what i'm talking about. I need to ovveride this message for "Value is incorrect. Required [type]"

I have custom Provider which implement `IValidationMetadataProvider` to customize response on model validation error, but those error is not catching there.

Comment: You have to post the action that return this message

Answer (score 0):

You have three options

1. Catch the Json exception in server middleware, interrogate it, and then convert it to something more succint for the client.  Search up "app.UseMiddleware<>()".
2. Inspect the status code of the HttpResponse message on the client, interrogate it, and then convert it to something more succinct for the UI.
3. Perform rudimentary format / variable type validations on the client before sending to the controller / API.

I would recommend approach 3.  The API has presented a contract to you for the payload.  The least the client / UI can do is make sure it complies with the contract.  Failures due to business logic / rules definitely do belong on the server.